# How to telnet via proxy authentication?

Tags: authentication, proxy, telnet

I am behind a proxy server in my college. It uses a simple username and password authentication. And i connect to the proxy server to port 3128. now i want to telnet simply to say any website on the internet like

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
```

this gives me

```
error telnet: could not resolve www.udacity.com/80: Name or service not known
```

How can I define the proxy settings for telnet? I have already set environment variables `http_proxy` and `HTTP_PROXY`. Also have applied system wide proxy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Proxychains for this.

First install proxychains, using the command:

```
$ apt-get install proxychains
```

Then configure your proxy settings in `/etc/proxychains.conf` file.

Add at last, these lines for HTTP and HTTPS proxy.

```
http    proxy-ip   proxy-port    username        password
https   proxy-ip   proxy-port    username        password
```

Now you can do telnet by using the following command:

```
$ proxychains telnet www.google.com 80
```

Comment: i am getting this error:                 aakash@sigdel:~$ proxychains telnet www.google.com 3128ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-response|: sigdel is not exist
|DNS-request| www.google.com 
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
|DNS-response|: www.google.com is not exist
telnet: could not resolve www.google.com/3128: Unknown error

Comment: @AakashSigdel: Sorry, the last command which I wrote should be `$ proxychains telnet www.google.com 80`. It should work now !!

Comment: @pradeepchhetri i got error when i use this   proxychains telnet www.google.com 80
`ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-response|: xyz does not exist
|DNS-request| www.google.com 
|S-chain|-<>-proxy-ip:proxy-port-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<--denied
|DNS-response|: www.google.com does not exist
telnet: could not resolve www.google.com/80: Unknown error`

Comment: @john I was seeing the same error; I got around it by commenting out the `proxy_dns` line in `/etc/proxychains.conf`.  I'm assuming this is because my proxy server does not provide DNS.

Answer (score 24):

You could *do what the browser does*, i.e. connect to the proxy,

```
$ telnet proxy-server 3128
```

and talk to it.  If there was no authentication, a simple `GET` request (followed by two newlines (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)) with a full hostname and protocol, e.g.

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

should suffice.  Since you need authentication, you need to provide your username and password base64-encoded in a `Proxy-Authentication` header, e.g.

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

To create the base64 string, you could use `echo -n username:password | openssl base64`

Comment: Link has been dead . can you update ?

Comment: Done (kind of)...

Comment: this works for checking http servers but what about a sFTP server?