# How to make netcat use an existing HTTP proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, netcat

I can access a web page just fine by directly hitting my web server as follows:

```
$ echo "GET /sample" | nc web-server 80
This is contents of /sample...
$
```

Now, I would like netcat to go via a Squid HTTP proxy (listening on port 3128), much like I can configure my Firefox browser via its proxy preferences and have it go via an HTTP proxy.

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
$ echo "GET /sample" | nc -x squid-proxy:3128 web-server 80
    <Seemed to be blocked FOREVER on input, so I killed it.>
<Ctrl-C>
$
```

---

Note: I'm using RHEL 5.3 version of netcat that has the following options:

```
$ nc --help
nc: invalid option -- -
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
  [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
  [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

Excerpt from the man page of `nc`:

```
 EXAMPLES
    <snip>
 Connect to port 42 of host.example.com via an HTTP proxy at 10.2.3.4, port 8080. 
 This example could also be used by ssh(1); see the ProxyCommand directive in
 ssh_config(5) for more information.
       $ nc -x10.2.3.4:8080 -Xconnect host.example.com 42
```

Now, because mine is not an ssh/SSL usecase, I'm not sure how to use the `-x` / `-X` options, or even whether I should be using them at all!

If there's more than one way to achieve the above goal (namely, routing netcat traffic via an HTTP proxy), then I would greatly appreciate if you could share them all.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Netcat is not a specialized HTTP client.  Connecting through a proxy server for Netcat thus means *creating a TCP connection through the server*, which is why it expects a SOCKS or HTTPS proxy with the `-x` argument, specified by `-X`:

```
 -X proxy_protocol
         Requests that nc should use the specified protocol when talking
         to the proxy server.  Supported protocols are “4” (SOCKS v.4),
         “5” (SOCKS v.5) and “connect” (HTTPS proxy).  If the protocol is
         not specified, SOCKS version 5 is used.
```

`connect` specifies a method for creating SSL (HTTPS) connections through a proxy server.  Since the proxy is not the other end point and the connection is endpoint-wise encrypted, a `CONNECT` request allows you to tunnel a point-to-point connection through an HTTP Proxy (if it is allowed). (I might be glossing over details here, but it's not the important point anyway; [details on "`HTTP CONNECT` tunneling" here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_Tunneling))

**So**, to connect to your webserver using a proxy, you'll have to do what the web browser would do - **talk to the proxy**:

```
$ nc squid-proxy 3128
GET http://webserver/sample HTTP/1.0
```

([That question has similarities to this one; I don't know if `proxychain` is of use here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36627/11539))

**Addendum**
A browser using an *ordinary* HTTP proxy, e.g. Squid (as I know it), does what more or less what the example illustrated, as Netcat can show you:  after the `nc` call, I configured Firefox to use 127.0.0.1 port 8080 as proxy and tried to open google, this is what was output (minus a cookie):

```
$ nc -l 8080
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
DNT: 1
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

By behaving *this way*, too, you can use Netcat to access a HTTP server through the HTTP proxy.
Now, what should happen if you try to access a HTTPS webserver?  The browser surely should not reveal the traffic to anyone *in the middle*, so a *direct connection* is needed; and this is where `CONNECT` comes into play.  When I again start `nc -l 8080` and try to access, say, `https://google.com` with the proxy set to `127.0.0.1:80`, this is what comes out:

```
CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Host: google.com
```

You see, the `CONNECT` requests asks the server for a direct connection to `google.com`, port `443` (https).  **Now**, what does this request do?

```
$ nc -X connect -x 127.0.0.1:8080 google.com 443
```

The output from the `nc -l 8080` instance:

```
CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.0
```

So it uses the same way to create a direct connection.  However, as this can of course be exploited for almost anything (using for example `corkscrew`), `CONNECT` requests are usually restricted to the obvious ports only.

Comment: @sr_ Could you elaborate just a little bit more on how a browser might be achieving the *... TCP connection through the server* part? Just like socks4, socks5, and connect, it seems there is a protocol for plain HTTP proxying as well. Would you please confirm this? Many thanks.

Comment: @BruceEdiger, yes, indeed.  I subtracted `0.1` to mask my ignorance. `:)`

Comment: @Harry Does my playing around with `nc` and Firefox clarify things a little?

Comment: @sr_ I tried `nc squid-proxy 3128` followed by `GET http://webserver/sample HTTP/1.0`, but got an HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden (Access denied error).

Comment: @sr_ You seem to be quite an expert in all this stuff related to proxies, the whole networking toolset. Where can I learn all this stuff? TCP/IP books teach you theory only and don't cover the Linux  and other popular tools in the networking toolset (like your proxychains in the other response of yours). Would greatly appreciate if you could point me to some books, links, where I can read both the concepts and then try some hands-on also. I feel so ignorant not knowing everything about openssl, stunnel, nc, etc.

Comment: @sr_ *"Does my playing around with nc and Firefox clarify things a little? – sr_"* Yes, I kind of understand what you're saying, but would also like to know how the browser can, at the level of socket API, make the connection go through the proxy server and what proxy server does at the level of socket API to forward the traffic back and forth.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, no idea.  Not an expert here, you see `:)` You can probably use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to tap your own `CONNECT` connection and gain insights...

Comment: *"Ugh, sorry, no idea."* Your `$ nc squid-proxy 3128` followed by typing out `GET http://web-server/sample` request seems to be working now. This time when I retried, for some reason I had started getting a `Unable to determine IP address from host name web-server` error. I promptly added `web-server` to my `/etc/hosts` and restarted Squid, and lo and behold, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: On RHEL, including Red Hat Universal Base Images, the command has clearer arguments: `nc --proxy-type http --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 google.com 443`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at socat: http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/README

Comment: Thanks, +1. Looks like a VERY sophisticated and complex tool. Tried `echo "GET /sample HTTP/1.0" | socat PROXY:squid-proxy:web-server:80,proxyport=3128 STDIN`, but got this error: `2012/05/17 06:56:23 socat[3135] E CONNECT web-server:80: Forbidden`. Now, just to see if I understood this tool right, I next tried the basic, non-proxy usage: `echo "GET /sample HTTP/1.0" | socat TCP4:web-server:80 STDIN`, but got no response back! So, obviously, I'm missing something here in the socat usage. Would appreciate if you could point out my mistake.

Comment: Ok, I could get the non-proxy version invocation to work by using `STDIO` (or, `-`) instead of `STDIN`. But the proxy version is still giving me the same error.

Comment: **Another update:** I tried `echo "GET http://web-server/sample" | socat - TCP:squid-proxy:3128` and it worked. Would you confirm if this is how I am supposed to use `socat` (instead of the the `PROXY:...` address specification)?

Comment: Hi, i haven't used it so much myself, but i think it's correct. Socat opens a plain TCP-Connection to the http-proxy and squid parses the http-GET and does the rest. Does it work for https btw.? And finally another link: http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html

Comment: No, I haven't gotten to trying https yet. I will soon be worrying about https as well.  Thanks.